# Python - Tkinter: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'grid'; Проблема с атрибутом grid

Tags: python, tkinter

С библиотекой Tkinter работаю совсем не долго, понравилась библиотека.

Но вот когда к кнопке добавил grid (Чтобы выглядело красиво), тогда и появилась ошибка: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'grid'.

Код не большой:

```
import pygame
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
pygame.init()
def play1():
    pygame.mixer.music.load("sound/1.mp3") #Loading File Into Mixer
    pygame.mixer.music.play() #Playing It In The Whole Device
my_button1 = Button(root,text="1",width=60,command=play1).pack()
my_button1.grid(row=0, column=0)
root.mainloop()
```

Я пробовал, то что писали на анг. форумах, но мне не помогло.
Есть идеи, буду очень благодарен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод `pack` ничего не возвращает. Соответственно, после его вызова в переменной `my_button1` окажется `None`. Естественно, у `None` нет методов, в том числе метода `grid`.

Answer (score 1):

@Insolor:

> В данном случае нужно просто убрать вызов .pack(), тем более что вы потом вы размещаете кнопку с помощью grid.